# Define function as the limit of sin(x)^n

Tags: limits, functions

Define $\ f(x) $ as a limit:

$\ f(x) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin (x)^n $

How does this function look like? Is it continuous?

I think of analysing $\ n = 2k $ (How can I write k belongs to N numbers?) and $\ n = 2k + 1.

f(x) = 
\begin{cases}  
\sin (x\%2k\pi), & \text{for n = 2k} \\
\sin (x), & \text{for n = 2k+1}
\end{cases}

I want to emphasise, that in the first case the values are in the range [0, 1], as if for x in [0, \pi].

I am wondering about secind case. Is there any limit? Therefore - what about continuity?

I suppose that my solution is quite wrong thus I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, I have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit at each point except for $-\pi/2+2k\pi$ for integers $k$, where it alternates between $-1$ and $1$. When the function is not $1$ or $-1$, the limit is $0$, and at $\pi/2+2k\pi$ the limit is $1$.

Thus there is no global limit function, but if there were, say if we were doing $|\sin x|^n$ instead, it would not be continuous.

Comment: So, it is continuous in this form or it isn't? I shouldn't care about even/odd $\ n $, only for x values?

Comment: @True There's no limit in the case you give. In my alternative there's a limit, but it's not continuous.

Comment: Therefore, if there is no limit, it cannot be continuous function, right?

Comment: @True That's a philosophical matter. It's not incorrect to say "every limit is continuous," vacuously, because there's is no limit. If you exclude the points where there is no limit, the remaining function with the restricted domain is not continuous.

Comment: OK, let's focus on this particular function. I am simply getting more confused.

Comment: @True You could say there's no continuous limit.

Comment: However, what about multiplying? i have corrected question so as to show that n is which approaches infinity.

Comment: @True That was the question I answered. I automatically assumed it was $n$ then deleted my answer when I saw it wasn't, then undeleted when I saw it was supposed to be $n$.